# why is not python regex code not working?

Tags: python, regex

I have pasted to code in which I have used regex library in python, while to work on regex I typecasted the x and y variable(in individual scripts) as string to work with regex functions but then also I'm unable to use that variable.

```
import re
field_value="CREDIT MEMO SHHAA00172362/AB2"
field_value=field_value.replace("CREDIT MEMO ","")
x=re.findall("/.*",field_value)
print(x)
if x:
  field_value=re.sub(str(x),"",field_value)
  print(field_value)
```

Why is the str type casting is not working on list x?

```
#Similarly:

import re
field_value='SICR-2205-11-0-00045-1'
y=re.findall('^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]',field_value)
if y:
  print(y)
  x=re.split("-",field_value,1)
  print(x[0])
  print(x[2])
  if x[0] == str(y):
    print('123')
```

Why the str type casting is not working on list y?

Comment: Please don't use images of code and errors. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question .

Comment: `y` (or `x` apparently) is a list (of *all* the results from `re.findall`. If you cast a list to a string, you get its string representation, which is something like `['SICR']`; *including* the brackets.

Comment: Please spend some time editing your code properly and using the preview option (which is right below the editing field), before posting the question.

Comment: I really fail to see what you are trying to accomplish here and why you are using regex. Can you explain what you are doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `re.findall()` always returns an array, even if it is empty or just contains one element.

So `str(y)` becomes the string `"['SICR']"`.

If what you actually want to compare is the first match `re.findall('^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]',field_value)` comes up with (in this case, `"SICR"`) with `x[0]`, then you actually want to do:

```py
if x[0] == y[0]:
    print('123')
```

Since `y[0]` is the first match `re.findall()` found.